# How to run a JAR file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jar, rdf, owl

I downloaded the conversion tool **RDF2RDF**(that takes in a file in a given format and outputs a file in another format) in the form of a JAR file. All I wish to do is to run this JAR file giving it two arguments: the absolute path to the file I intend to convert and the name of the output file.

I copied the JAR file to my working directory and created a new external tool (run -> external tools -> external tools configuration -> program). I then configured the tool as follows:

Location: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_51\bin\java.exe

Working Directory: ${workspace_loc}

Arguments:
-jar ${workspace_loc:/name_of_jar_file.jar} ${workspace_loc:/source_file.owl} output_file.nt

When I run the external tool, I get the following error:
**Variable references non-existent resource : ${workspace_loc:/rdf2rdf-1.0.1-2.3.1}**

Is my configuration wrong?? Does anyone know how to use the RDF2RDF tool?

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy and paste the exact arguments used?
From what the error message says, the problem may be that you used `-jar ${workspace_loc:/name_of_jar_file}`, not `-jar ${workspace_loc:/name_of_jar_file.jar}`

Comment: I actually tried both ${workspace_loc:/name_of_jar_file.jar} and ${workspace_loc:/name_of_jar_file} but they both give me the same error. The arguments are: ${workspace_loc:/source_file.owl} and output_file.nt